# Bash Command to Add File to Git Working Directory, Then Remove When Job Completes - Jenkins

Tags: bash, git, jenkins

I had this setup at my previous job, but can't remember what the specific command is, and can't find any examples at my new job.  I have a creds file I want to pull into git when the job runs, then remove when the job completes, so the creds aren't stored on git.

So basically pre-build load the file from the Jenkins server to the working directory Git is expecting it to be in, then removing it from the WD once the job completes.

Comment: No.  Just no.  Anything that automatically manipulates a git repo is fundamentally broken.  Source control is for humans.  If you want a versioned file system, or some other functionality, use a different tool.  But it sounds like you don't actually want to write the credentials into git, you just want them in the working directory.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, manipulate the working directory.  Will edit my question to reflect, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you use the builtin Jenkins Credentials functionality? It can store many types of secrets. Tokens, Username/Passwords, Private Keys, Secret files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was a lot simpler than I was thinking:

`cp ${JENKINS_HOME}/path_to_creds_file ${WORKSPACE}/path_to_dummy_file_to_overwrite`

Followed by the post build step of:

`rm ${WORKSPACE}/path_to_dummy_file_to_overwrite`

Comment: There's a downside to this. Any user with SSH access to the Jenkins can see the file. Or with the Script Console, you can simply print the file content by any user who can login to the Jenkins UI. This a security flaw in Jenkins and make sure you've blocked the Script Console if you take this approach.

Comment: So locking down access the box and Jenkins will prevent both of those access methods, or limit to a list of known trusted people.

Comment: If you evaluate that has minimal security risk and adequate for you; that's your decision. I just want to give you the facts that Jenkins has some security flaws they addressing slowly.

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins provides credentials support via the [Credentials Binding plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/credentials-binding)

This plugin allows several kinds of credentials or secrets like user:password, tokens, secrets texts, secrets files, etc to be bound to environment variables (and if you have installed de ssh plugin too you will have the ssh key credentials available as well)

You can consume the credentials and secrets as environment vars inside the withCredentials() blocks, and is fully Jenkinsfile Pipeline syntax compatible, you can find the documentation [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/)

Some examples of usage of the credentials in scripted Pipelines (that work also on declarative pipelines) are:

```
node {
  withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'mytoken', variable: 'TOKEN')]) {
    sh '''
      set +x
      curl -H "Token: $TOKEN" https://some.api/
    '''
  }
}
```

```
node {
  dir('subdir') {
    withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'secret', variable: 'FILE')]) {
      sh 'use $FILE'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I did try using the plugin, was unable to figure out how to pass those variables to my test framework(Karate).  The tests we run don't require the complexity of a pipeline job config.

Comment: Have a look at the [Jenkins Syntax docs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/) especially the [Environemnt](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment) section where it tells you how to load credentials from the builtin plugin to the pipeline environment.